# Debugging C using Visual Studio Code on Windows

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a C program using Visual Studio Code on Windows 10,
which I have the **C/C++** extension installed in.

My problem is that when I create `Source.c` in my workspace ( `E:\Docs\c` ), write some code then hit **F5**, it shows an error message `launch: program 'E:\Docs\c\a.exe' does not exist`, which means VSCode doesn't do the compiling thing.

Meanwhile when I go to the console and type `gcc source.c`, which creates `a.exe` in the same folder, and hit **F5** again it starts with no problems, but doing that every time I want to run the code is annoying.

So, is there a way to compile the code from inside VSCode ?

Here is my `c_cpp_properties.json` :

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\lib\\gcc\\i686-w64-mingw32\\8.1.0\\include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

And this is `launch.json` :

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should add prelaunched task with label of your build task to *launch.json* like this:

```
"preLaunchTask": "build" // label of your build task
```

This means you should have in your tasks.json following task with label *build* e.g.

```
    "tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "gcc -g source.c"
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
```

Also "-g" flag is important for enabling debugging

Comment: Hello, where should I add "preLaunchTask": "build" // label of your build task ?

Comment: @Pierre-LouisDeschamps add it to configuration in `launch.json`